# How to remove all data about users from database from heroku server?

Tags: django, heroku

I created many test accounts in my heroku server. Now they all have empty columns, and therefore do not work. And now I want to remove all data about existing users/accounts, including superuser, then recreate. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
You can go to your terminal, where you have executed the command 'python manage.py runserver' and execute the command - 'python manange.py shell', then your shell will start.

Then execute the command:-

step-1: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

step-2: User.objects.all().delete() # this will delete all the user from your table

step-3: exit() # exit from the shell

step-4: python manage.py createsuperuser # for creating the superuser
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As far as I know, this will delete all users only from the local server, but how can i do it for heroku server?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally in server side.

Go to your heroku database and reset database from the setting.
after that.

1. `$ heroku run python manage.py makemigration`s
2. `$ heroku run python manage.py migrate`
3. Create New Admin ( can be any or the same your existing)

All done, 100% that works for me.